# Numerical integration in C

Tags: integration

I have written a program involving a lot of calculations and I finally have to integrate this one final function that I have labelled as 'A[i]', where A[i] = B*E[i].
I have tried to directly integrate it; without using any method. My upper limit of the integral, E[n], is fixed. But in each iteration, I want my lower limit to change. I want it to be the next value of E. I have put this integration in the 'j' loop. 'n' is the number of divisions that I've made and 'h' is the width of each division, like how it is done in Trapezoidal rule. I have defined n and h in the program.

So, my integration looks like this:

```
double s=0;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
A[i]=B*E[i];        
if(i==(n-1) || (i==0))
                s=s+A[i];
            else
                s=s+2*A[i];
  }

      for(j=1;j<99;j++)
        {   
             s=s-A[j]-A[j+1];
         I[j]=s*(h/2);
        }
```

I[j] is my final integration.

Here, to change the lower limit in each iteration, I have eliminated the previous one division E, as I move further with each increasing j.
It looks like a correct logic to me but my graph plot does not turn out to be the way I want it to look like. It gives me a lot of constant values toward the end. Is there any other logic to get what I want? I can think of adding, instead of subtracting but I'm not quite sure how to put it up.

Comment: Can you please post your full code? the above code is not valid C code.

Comment: Why do you hate indentation and whitespace?